# How to symbol a sub-group?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group and $H$ is subgroup of $G$, can I mark like this:
$$K\prec G\;\;$$

Or I need to do this $$K<G\;\;$$

Thank you!

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Notation_for_subgroup_properties

Comment: The second option is, I believe, widely used internationally, whereas the first option is much used for logic/set theory stuff, like partial orders and etc.

Comment: I found another source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols Thanks for all of you!

Answer (score 4):

I usually go with the second symbol. Note that there $<$ is used if $K$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Otherwise $\leq$ can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the most used for a proper subgroup is the symbol $<$, otherwise $\leq$.
If you see $H \triangleleft G$, it means $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. The expression $L_1 \prec L_2$ is used to show that $L_1$ is Karp reducible to $L_2$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If H is a subgroup of G, and is not equal to G, then use $<$, otherwise use $\leq$.